# Javascript filter function

Tags: javascript, filter

```
$("tr[class*='nowrap']").filter(function () {
    return $("#DS_coords")
    .val()
    .indexOf(
        $(this)
        .find("td:eq(2)")
        .text()
        .match(/\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/)
    ) != -1;
}).find("input[id*='editInput']")
    .val("huidigenaam")
    .next("input")
    .click();
})
```

This piece of code works. However, I want to change `"huidigenaam"` in a variable called `huidigenaam`, which I want to get like this:

```
if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().indexOf("sometext") < 0) {
    var huidigenaam = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text() + "someteext"
}else{
    var huidigenaam = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
}
```

`$(this)` should be the `"tr[class*='nowrap']"` (so if my filter matches, also get the `.text()` from the first `td` in the `tr`. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: You seem to have a extra set of `})` at the end of your first piece of code. Is that a copy-paste mistake?

Comment: Yeah, it's a click function before that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr[class*='nowrap']").each(function() {

    if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().indexOf("Ausfake") < 0) {
        var huidigenaam = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text() + "Ausfake";
    }else{
    var huidigenaam = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    }

$(this).filter(function () {


    return $("#DS_coords").val().indexOf($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text().match(/\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}/)) != -1;

}).find("input[id*='editInput']").val(huidigenaam).next("input").click();



})
})
```